# SQL 2008 R2 user permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2; Mixed authentication mode.  We don't have a fully certified DBA yet, so we're looking for some advice or direction.

We have an application that will get used to view/update some sensitive data.  Some of the users will be outside users,  and some will be internal users (in windows active directory).  For a select few internal users,  we want to loosen the permissions (when coming from this application) so they can see and update all data.  What's the best way to do this?  We're considering sending a different connection string  for certain users so that proper permissions can be applied on sql server.  For internal users, we plan on using windows authentication to sql; outside users  will use a connection string with sql server authentication.  Then inside sql server, depending on the Login, we would use different Views or Sprocs to pull/update the data and act accordingly. Are we going down the right path?

Also, because the decision has to be made in the application to know what connection string to send, this seems a little dangerous because any IT person could manipulte this to give themselves extra permissions.  Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle the permissions on the application layer and give the application the least permission it needs. I.e. no need create/delete tables if the application doesn't create/delete table. This is assuming your users don't connect to the sql server directly and goes through the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ysrb, are you saying it would be better to use one connection string from an application?

Comment: Yes. One connection string. One data layer. One service layer (where you handle auth authorize, etc).